# Fast-twitch hand muscle exercises?

Tags: exercise, muscle, speed, hands

A friend who spent some time in the military told me about a silent language in which the hands are signed in short, rapid bursts. Really, really rapid bursts, actually.

I've seen videos of both [wing chun](http://youtu.be/tuH-GYUHyQw) and [speed stacking](http://youtu.be/8GaLEY17G_Y), but these seem to be about the arms, more or less exclusively. I have yet to find anything on fast *hands* on the internet, and I've been searching for a while. I've seen some people speaking relatively quick sign language on a city bus, so I'm inclined to believe my military friend.

**Are there exercises to improve manual dexterity? Anywhere from the wrist to the digits -- how can I get more use from the fast-twitch muscles in my hands?**

Bonus points if you can tell me what that military language is, or if he was pulling my leg :P

Comment: Sign language speed is a matter of practice. There are many different military hand signals used from regular patrol units up through SpecOps (Special Operations), and they can be sequenced in quick succession to give silent orders/notifications.

Comment: @JohnP I haven't been able to find any vids on the military hand signals anywhere. Re: sign language - I'm primarily interested in increasing the speed in my hands, although on an unrelated note I am also interested in learning sign language and understand it's a matter of practice. Muscle memory and all that.